# Update Tensorboard while keeping Tensorflow old with conda

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda, tensorboard

I have some legacy Keras/Tensorflow code, which is unstable using latest Tensorflow versions (1.13+). It works just fine with previous versions. However i want to use Pytorch's Tensorboard support which requires it to be 1.14+. I've installed all Tensorflow-related packages to 1.10 and wanted to do just `conda install tensorboard=1.14` but it removes tensorflow=1.10 as a requirement. I know that these packages are generally independent. How to upgrade tensorboard while keeping tensorflow old? Preferably i would like to use a single conda environment.

Comment: Not sure if it works but have you tried `conda update tensorboard=1.14 tensorflow=1.13.2` (or `tensorflow-gpu`)?

Comment: @jdehesa, i've tried `conda install tensorboard=1.14 tensorflow=1.*` all stops with requirement  tensorflow=1.13 -> tensorboard[version='>=1.13.0,<1.14.0']

Comment: Ah I see, so it's TF that requires a specific version of TB. Not sure if you could force it with [`--no-deps`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/update.html#Solver%20Mode%20Modifiers)? One alternative is to have a separate environment for TensorBoard only...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @jdehesa suggested in the comments, it's better to have a different conda environment for pytorch and then install just the tb there
`!pip install tb-nightly`